# Select ng-options group names are not updating | Dynamic ng-options groups

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a dropdown select with grouped ng-options. The user should be able to dynamically change the naming of the group name in an input field. **On change of the group name value the select directive is not being updated** unless you make a new selection.

Anybody had the same kind of problem?

**Here's the jsbin:** http://jsbin.com/ziyeduzalo/edit?html,js,output

**This is how my code looks:** 
.js

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},

];


$scope.change = function() {
  $scope.players[0].team = 'new-group-name';
};
```

.html

```
<select ng-options="player.name group by player.team for player in players " ng-model="systemType.tertiaryEquipment"></select>
```

**UPDATE:** This seem to work in older versions of angular then 1.4.x.

Comment: I don't understand why but this example is working in jsfiddle check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/66mojr47/2/)

Comment: It's because of the Angular.js version. Try changing it from 1.0.x to 1.4.x and it won't work.

Comment: in your example put `track by player.team` on the end of ng-options. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3938/)

Comment: and the version of angular is 1.4.9

Comment: This is the right answer! Thanks!

Comment: But be careful track by should be a way of tracking unique objects so i think it works because of a strange way since the optgroup are unique on the select but not on the list if you use a normal select only with options and not optgroup track by must be used on something that unique identify the option. this feels more like a cheat that a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here, i've edited a copy of your js bin. Basically i've told angularJS to re-compile the select input, for it to change.

This is done within a controller, which is a **BAD PRACTICE**, create a custom directive to do such manipulations. And use provided `element` variable for selecting DOM element `select` instead of `document.querySelector()`

http://jsbin.com/miyecireba/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a very ugly way of doing it. Hopefully there are better ways for fixing this.

Comment: Currently, in the bin, it is. If you create yourself a directive, its not too bad. Re-compiling one DOM element is not heavy for the user

Answer (score 1):

For others that may come to this problem the resolution for this particular problem where to use the track by.

Track by should be used to identify the options as unique in the `select`, so there should be diferent approach on if this is the real solution to this.

Since the `ng-options` `group by` will generate `optgroups` we use that in advantage so we can use the `track by` on the object of the `group by`.
The optgroups will be unique on the display of the `select`.

So in this case:

```
<select ng-options="player.name group by player.team for player in players track by player.team" ng-model="systemType.tertiaryEquipment"></select>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3938/)**

**Note:**
Angular version 1.4.9 used to test this.